# Typescript does not load file with same name as parent folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have such files:
`app.ts` and `config/config.ts`

When from app.ts I try to import or require config:

```
import './config/config';
```

config file completely ignored(code inside `config/config.ts` is not executed) and no error occur (such as no module found), but If I rename `config.ts` for example to `config-loader.ts` and try to import `config/config-loader` - this works perfectly.

Can someone explain why I can't use file same name as parent folder to load this file later?

UPD:
here is content of app.ts file

```
import {foo} from './config/config';
console.log('from app');
console.log(foo);
```

./config/config.ts:

```
console.log('test from config');
export const foo = 'bar';
```

app is run with
`ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register app.ts`
in console after run I see:

```
from app
undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to import an exported module from that file.

```
import {Config} from './config/config';
```

where Config is your exported module.

You can also use the JS way like

```
const config = require("./config/config")
```

but you will lose the typings.

In your case, the below means run a script.

```
import './config/config';
```

runs the script 'config'.

Comment: All 3 option didn't run ./config/config file and config is undefined, without any errors....

Comment: If possible, can you post the contents in your config.ts file? And please try deleting the dist folder and try once again.